# Fancybox for the second gallery group displaying only one image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Ok so here's the thing I have two galleries and two rel groups. The first gallery (group1) opens well and shows all the images present in the fancy box. However the second gallery(group2) opens up but displays only one image when there are 5 images in the set.

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 pd0 width33 bdr_phmnsgg" style="margin-left:20px;">
 <span class="font14 photo_menu_heading pd_top10 pd_bot10 dsp_block">
 Photo Gallery
 </span>
 <?php $items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'g_tourism_gimage', false); 
 $i=0;
 ?>
 <?php foreach ( $items as $item) { 
 if($i==0){
 ?>
 <a  href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $item,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" >
 <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $item); ?>
 </a>
 <?php }else{
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $item,'full' ); ?>" style="display:none;" class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" >
 <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $item ); ?>
 </a>
 <?php } $i++;

 } ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 pd0 width33 mrgn_btm10 bdr_phmnsgg1" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">
 <span class="font14 photo_menu_heading pd_bot10 pd_top10 dsp_block">Menu</span>
 <?php $menus = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goan_tourism_menuimage', true); 
 ?>

 <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $menus,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group2"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $menus); ?></a>
 </div>
```

And below is the jquery declaration:

```
<script>
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
</script>
```

This is the edited code: Sorry for the delay was just checking how I had done it earlier

```
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 pd0 width33 mrgn_btm10 bdr_phmnsgg1">
  <span class="font14 photo_menu_heading pd_top10 pd_bot10 dsp_block">
 Menu
 </span>
 <?php $items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goan_tourism_menuimage', true); 
 $j=0;
 ?>
 <?php foreach ( $menus as $menu) { 
 if($j==0){
 ?>
 <a  href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $menu,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements fancybox" id="group2" rel="group2" >
 <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $menu); ?>
 </a>
 <?php }else{
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $menu,'full' ); ?>" style="display:none;" id="group2" class="grouped_elements fancybox" id="group2" rel="group2" >
 <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $menu ); ?>
 </a>
 <?php } $j++;

 } ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not looping over that second link, so you're actually only outputting one image. You'll need to add another `foreach` into your code.

You might be better off not targetting the a tag and just using the fancybox class like so...

```
<a  href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $item,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group1">
```

and

```
<a  href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $menus,'full' ); ?>"class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group2">
```

And then call Fancybox like so

```
<script>
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
</script>
```

Full edited code below

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 pd0 width33 bdr_phmnsgg" style="margin-left:20px;">
<span class="font14 photo_menu_heading pd_top10 pd_bot10 dsp_block">Photo Gallery</span>

 <?php 
    $items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'g_tourism_gimage', false); 
    $i=0;
 ?>
<?php foreach ( $items as $item) { 
    if($i==0){
?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $item,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group1"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $item); ?></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $item,'full' ); ?>" style="display:none;" class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group1"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $item ); ?></a>
<?php } $i++;
 }
?>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 pd0 width33 mrgn_btm10 bdr_phmnsgg1" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">
     <span class="font14 photo_menu_heading pd_bot10 pd_top10 dsp_block">Menu</span>
        <?php $menus = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goan_tourism_menuimage', true); 

foreach ( $menus as $menu) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $menu,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group2"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $menu); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
 </div>

<script>
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
</script>
```

Looks like you're also missing a space before your class attribute in your second link, update to below.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $menus,'full' ); ?>" class="grouped_elements fancybox" rel="group2"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $menus); ?></a>
```

Comment: Hi Pete, i changed it as you said but the second gallery loads on a page, rather than fancybox

Comment: same as before the fancybox just opens up a single image, no left/right navigation buttons

Comment: Hmm, do you have a demo link at all?

Comment: Just noticed you have a missing space before your class attribute in the second link. Code updated. You also don't appear to be looping over that second link, so you're only outputting one image. You need another foreach loop

Comment: i tried looping it similarly to the first link but the whole page didn't load

Comment: Can you update your code for me please so I can see how you looped?

Comment: I have edited it Pete, If you could please have a look and let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: <?php $items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goan_tourism_menuimage', true);

You are declaring $items again, instead of $menus. See my updated code